# Is there any product size chart gem in Spree commerce ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend, spree

We want to show size chart for the products in spree commerce.

The only thing I could find regarding this is `https://github.com/sbounmy/spree_size_chart`, but this is considerably out-of-date;

Any help on this.?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is to raise a question on the repository you found there, or just fork it and update it to support the version of Spree you are using.

The extension looks simple enough to upgrade or even rebuild yourself from scratch.